# Attaching SqlDataSourceEnumerator to Combobox Event. C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, combobox, sqldatasource

I'm in a bind with this one and spinning my wheels now.
Here is what I have that grabs the local network SQL instances and puts them in my combobox1 quite nicely.

```
SqlDataSourceEnumerator sdse = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
        DataTable table = sdse.GetDataSources();
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(row["ServerName"].ToString() + "\\" + row["InstanceName"].ToString());
        }
```

This works great when attached to a button click event.  But takes a long time and isn't very simple for the user.

My question is, how can I get this to run when the combobox is clicked? and then also show in the combobox?
I want the actions to be essentially the same as Windows' ODBC selection. You click the combobox, and then it populates.

I've tried the following to no avail.  No errors, but it just doesn't fly.

```
private void comboBox1_ComboDropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSourceEnumerator sdse = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
        DataTable table = sdse.GetDataSources();
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(row["ServerName"].ToString() + "\\" + row["InstanceName"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

I've also tried DropDown and MouseDown with no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind.
Had to add an eventhandler to the combobox like this.

```
this.SQLComboBox.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.SQLComboBox_MouseDown);
```

Then, in the code for the combobox, I used this.

```
private void SQLComboBox_MouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSourceEnumerator sdse = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
        DataTable table = sdse.GetDataSources();
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            SQLComboBox.Items.Add(row["ServerName"].ToString() + "\\" + row["InstanceName"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

Works like a charm!